# "How to fix "TypeError: 'PAO' object is not subscriptable" when trying to extract value from a Python object?"

Tags: python, typeerror, attributeerror

I loop through a list of objects and for every object I want to extract a value using a valid key.
The objects are instances of a class I created. Neither dot notation nor bracket notation is working.
If I use dot notation I get this error: AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'number'
If I use bracket notation, cause it looks like a dict to me, I get this error: TypeError: 'PAO' object is not subscriptable
The error occurs in line 17

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import json

# add a class
def add():
    # collect data
    number = e_filter_var.get()
    person = e_p_var.get()
    action = e_a_var.get()
    obj = e_o_var.get()
    # save the card
    for elem in cards:
        print(type(elem))
        print(elem)
        # update existing card
        if elem['number'] == number:
            elem['person'] = person
            elem['action'] = action
            elem['object'] = obj
        # add new card
        else:
            card = PAO(number, person, action, obj)
            cards.append(card)
    save_data(cards)

# load card`s data
def on_card_click(event):
    e_filter_var.set("{:03}".format(event.widget.card_value))
    for elem in cards:
        if elem['number'] == "{:03}".format(event.widget.card_value):
            e_p_var.set(elem['person'])
            e_a_var.set(elem['action'])
            e_o_var.set(elem['object'])
        else:
            e_p_var.set("")
            e_a_var.set("")
            e_o_var.set("")

# load data
def load_data():
    with open("data.json") as f:
        return json.load(f)
    
# save data
def save_data(data):
    with open("data.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(data, f, default=lambda x: x.__json__(), indent=2)



root = Tk()
root.title("PAO_Project1")

# laod data
cards = load_data()

# main frame
mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding=5)
mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

# frame for buttons and entry
controlframe = ttk.Frame(mainframe, padding=5)
controlframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(W, E))

# frame for the pao objects
cardframe = ttk.Frame(mainframe, padding=5)
cardframe.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky=(W, E))

# create widgets
l = ttk.Label(controlframe, width=7, text="#143")
l.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky=(W, E))

e_p_var = StringVar()
e_p = ttk.Entry(controlframe, width=21, textvariable=e_p_var)
e_p.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky=(W, E))

e_a_var = StringVar()
e_a = ttk.Entry(controlframe, width=21, textvariable=e_a_var)
e_a.grid(column=1, row=1, sticky=(W, E))

e_o_var = StringVar()
e_o = ttk.Entry(controlframe, width=21, textvariable=e_o_var)
e_o.grid(column=2, row=1, sticky=(W, E), columnspan=2)

b_add = ttk.Button(controlframe, width=4, text="Add", command=add)
b_add.grid(column=4, row=1, sticky=(W, E))

c_var = StringVar()
c = ttk.Combobox(controlframe, width=7, textvariable=c_var)
c.grid(column=0, row=2, sticky=(W, E))
c['values'] = ('000-099', '100-199', '200-299', '300-399', '400-499', '500-599', '600-699', '700-799', '800-899', '900-999')

e_filter_var = StringVar()
e_filter = ttk.Entry(controlframe, width=7, textvariable=e_filter_var)
e_filter.grid(column=1, row=2, sticky=(W, E))

e_random_var = StringVar()
e_random = ttk.Entry(controlframe, width=3, textvariable=e_random_var)
e_random.grid(column=2, row=2, sticky=(W, E))

b_random = ttk.Button(controlframe, text="Random", width=4)
b_random.grid(column=3, row=2, sticky=(W, E), columnspan=2)

for child in controlframe.winfo_children(): 
    child.grid_configure(padx=5, pady=5)

for child in cardframe.winfo_children(): 
    child.grid_configure(padx=10, pady=10)

# define a class
class PAO:
    def __init__(self, number, person, action, obj):
        self.number = number
        self.person = person
        self.action = action
        self.obj = obj

    def __json__(self):
        return {
            'number': self.number,
            'person': self.person,
            'action': self.action,
            'object': self.obj
        }

# create and style the cards
s = ttk.Style()
s.configure("Frame.TFrame", borderwidth=2, relief="solid")

for i in range(0, 2):
    for j in range(0, 20):

        test_frame = ttk.Frame(cardframe, style="Frame.TFrame", padding=15)
        test_frame.grid(column=j, row=i, sticky=(W, E))

        card_value =  i * 20 + j # calculate card value based on row and column
        card_label = ttk.Label(test_frame, text="#{:03d}".format(card_value))
        card_label.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(W, E))

        card_label.card_value = card_value # attach card value to frame widget
        card_label.bind("<Button-1>", on_card_click) # attach click handler   
        

root.mainloop()
```

As said, I tried dot notation and bracket notation, treating it as an object and as a dictionary.
The print(type(elem)) statement says this: <class 'dict'>
The print(elem) ensures that there is a valid key called 'number': {'number': '000', 'person': 'Cat', 'action': 'climbs up on a', 'object': 'tree'}

This here is the json data containing the list of one dictionary:

```json
[
  {
    "number": "000",
    "person": "Cat",
    "action": "climbs up on a",
    "object": "tree"
  }
]
```

Comment: Can't reproduce the error, so you should document the exact steps to get the error, as well as edit the question with the full stack trace of the error.

Comment: From the looks of the code, the `json.load` will make a list of dictionaries in `cards`, but when `card` is created it is a `PAO` object, not a dictionary, and when added to `cards` that PAO object won't act like a dictionary.  Either put dictionaries in `cards` or `PAO` objects in `cards`, don't mix.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.